# Why is Could not find Fragment Constructor thrown when the Fragment has empty constructor?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, constructor, crash

In Crashlytics reports, I have received 3 crash details on the same device for a single user running Android 10.

The error is:

```
Caused by androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Unable to instantiate fragment d.a.a.a.a.c: could not find Fragment constructor
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java:563)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainer.instantiate(FragmentContainer.java:57)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$3.instantiate(FragmentManager.java:390)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.<init>(FragmentStateManager.java:74)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.restoreSaveState(FragmentManager.java:2466)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1707)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1684)
       at com.tinyfold.app.post.PostFragment.onCreate(PostFragment.java:79)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2685)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2583)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1708)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1684)
       at com.tinyfold.app.feed.FeedFragment.onCreate(FeedFragment.java:80)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2685)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2583)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.restoreChildFragmentState(Fragment.java:1708)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.onCreate(Fragment.java:1684)
       at androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment.onCreate(NavHostFragment.java:206)
       at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:2685)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.create(FragmentStateManager.java:280)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1187)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1368)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1446)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1509)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2637)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchCreate(FragmentManager.java:2583)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchCreate(FragmentController.java:236)
       at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreate(FragmentActivity.java:315)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:115)
       at com.tinyfold.app.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1306)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3310)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3484)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2068)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7551)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:995)
```

It is working fine on my device and in the emulator, and I haven't received any other crash reports as of now.

Here's how PostFragment looks:

```
class PostFragment constructor() : Fragment() {

    private var actionsListener: FeedAdapter.ActionsListener? = null

    private val gson = Gson()
//...
//OMITTED
//...
    companion object {
        fun newInstance(
                post: Post?,
                listener: FeedAdapter.ActionsListener
        ): PostFragment {
            val gson = Gson()
            val data = Bundle()
            // ...OMITTED... (some json manipulaton)
            val fragment = PostFragment() <--- Empty
            fragment.setListener(listener)
            fragment.arguments = cardData
            return fragment
        }
    }

}
```

Here's how `FeedFragment` looks:

```
class FeedFragment constructor() : Fragment(), FeedAdapter.ActionsListener {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FeedFragment()
    }

//...
//OMITTED
//...
}
```

**EDIT:**

Here's what `d.a.a.a.a.c` points to:

```
class PostSourcesBottomSheet(private val sources: List<String>) :
        BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment(doNotDim = true) {
}
```

`BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment`

```
open class BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment(
    private val disableKeyboardHideFunction: Boolean = false,
    private val doNotDim: Boolean = false
) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {
}
```

This is extremely confusing as I do not have a Fragment that does not have an empty constructor. What could be the issue here and how can I resolve this (I am unable to reproduce it as well) ?

Comment: Do you have the proguard map to lookup what `d.a.a.a.a.c` is?

Comment: @maurice Yes, have updated my question

Comment: It looks like `PostSourcesBottomSheet`'s constructor has parameters, so fragment manager won't be able to find the "empty" version of the constructor. What if you add a parameterless constructor to it? (If `BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment` is not abstract that should have a parameterless constructor too)

Comment: @maurice Thank you. I will try adding an empty constructor to `PostSourcesBottomSheet's` and moving `BaseBottomSheetDialogFragment` to separate methods.